# AS3: Preloader Not Working w/ Exported for AS Graphics

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a lot of graphics and sounds in my library that are exported for Actionscript in Frame 1. I believe that because of the exported graphics, my preloader will not work. All I get is a white frame while the movie loads.

How can you preload graphics that are exported for Actionscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export for Actionscript in Frame 1, everything that is exported must be loaded before any content is visible.  I usually uncheck this button, and then everything is exported to the first frame where it's referenced.  For more details on this approach, check out http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html .  Howwever, if you're like most developers, you probably reference *everything* from your main document Class, so this may not do you much good.  It does offer the possibility that you can avoid a preloader altogether, though, because loading is spread across different frames.

If your movie is structured like normal, check out http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/4/22/Tutorial-Preloading-Actionscript-3-AS3-Games-in-Flash-CS3/ .

Answer (score 0):

It is not applicable on every case, but maybe you can preloader in separate file, which loads your main swf. 
You can see detailed how to in this tutorial: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=85